# Zend Framework: Autoloading Modules

Tags: zend-framework, module

in [Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart/create-a-model-and-database-table),

```
protected function _initAutoload() {
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Default_',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
    ));
    return $autoloader;
}
```

i thought if the namespace was 'Default', i dont need to specify it?

eg. their class also has Default_ appended to it

```
class Default_Model_Guestbook
```

isit required? or isit better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual states it is certainly not required. But you could say it's a good practice. 
If you do namespace it you could edit your 'default module' in the config and you don't have to go namespace the previous default one...

this can be done by setting the prefixDefaultModule:

```
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = 1
```

also have a look at this question: [Dynamic default mdoule in ZF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875747/dynamic-default-module-in-zend-framework)

Comment: by "If you do namespace it you could edit your 'default module' in the config" do u mean i can do something like default.resources.db.adapter...? and what u mean by "you don't have to go namespace the previous default one..."

Comment: let's say you have a default module 'mymodule', which is not namespaced. And one day in your config you say: resources.frontController.defaultModule = 'news', then your 'mymodule' module is not the default anymore, and you will have to go prefix it with 'Mymodule_'

Comment: oh so if in the config i specify defaultModule = 'news', the 'mymodule' module will not work (without a prefix)?

Comment: that's right, because only the default module can work without a prefix